# Odds on winning both hands running it twice when massive dog

Tags: pot-odds

Just saw a hand on Stars where red QQ got it all in pre-flop against black AA. They both had their run it twice settings on, and the boards ran out like this:

6s Js Kc Qc 3c - giving QQ top set and half the pot

Jh Ks 4h 6h 9h - giving QQ a flush and the other half, $101.25 in all.

What would be the odds of this happening? I understand the first board, QQ was a 4-1 underdog (18.96% vs 80.69%), but for the second board QQ has one less out, making by my calculations only a 10% chance of winning.

Is the calculation 18.96% x 10.39% i.e. about a 1.97% chance of winning both pots?

Comment: First pot: plug them into the calculator. Second pot: plug them into the calculator while removing the first 5 community cards. Multiply both numbers and you got the right answer. I haven't checked your numbers, but they look okay

Comment: Not the exact numbers I get but close.

Answer (score 3):

First pot, you have 19.14% equity and 18.78% to win. Second pot, with card removal you have 13.5% equity and 13.09% to win. To calculate your odds to win both, simply multiply both numbers:

```
.1878 * .1309 = 0.02458
```

So odds are 2.46% or 1 : 41.